# How to add markers in html5 video player on video progress indication bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple custom HTML 5 video player, I would like to add markers to my video player, progress indication bar something like this.

[image]

So far Here is my solution just for one marker at 0.6s.

HTML

```
<div canplay id="video-block">
    <div id="video-container">
        <video id="videoplayer" ref="video"  autoplay webkit-playsinline playsinline>
            <source src="videos/vmerce.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

    </div>
    <div id="video-controls" style="position: relative; display: block">
        <div id="seek-bar-container">
            <div id="seek-bar">
                <div id="current-time">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pause-play-button">
            <img id="play" src="images/play.png"> 
            <img id="pause" src="images/pause.png" style="display:none">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is js to add markers

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //get videoplayer tag element
        var videoplayerID =document.getElementById("videoplayer");
        var ranges = [{
            from: 0,
            to: 6
        },
        {
            from: 6,
            to: 9
        },
        {
            from: 9,
            to: 25
        },
        {
            from: 25,
            to: 38
        }, 
    ];

    console.log(ranges[0].to);

        videoplayerID.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
            if ($(this)[0].duration) {
                $(this).parent().parent().find("#current-time").css("width", ($(this)[0].currentTime * 100 / $(this)[0].duration) + "%");
            }

            if (this.currentTime >= ranges[0].to) {

                var bb =$('<div class="bubles"></div>')

                $("#current-time").append(bb);

            }
        });


})
```

Now when I run my app I get the following.

[image]

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Comment: You are adding your marker, but you are not giving it a position. Outside of the `timeupdate` listener add your markers to the bar and position them with the `left` property. And put them in a separate element since the width of `#current-time` changes.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier can you show me thought code as an answer? I will appreciate that thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track with calculating the `width` of the `#current-time` bar. Outside of the `timeupdate` listener do the same for each `range` or `marker`.

Loop over each `position` of the marker and calculate the offset of the `left` property just like you did with the `width` property. This will give you the position of each marker on the timeline.

Then in the loop create each marker, give it the `left` property value and add them, for example, to the `#seekbar`.

```js
// Video and seekbar
const video = document.getElementById('videoplayer');
const seekBar = document.getElementById('seekbar');

// Positions of markers in seconds.
const positions = [3, 6.5, 7];

// Set the markers when we CAN know the duration of the video.
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {

  // Add each marker to the #seekbar element.
  positions.forEach(function(position) {

    // Is position within range of the duration?
    if (position <= video.duration) {

      // Calculate position in percentage..
      const left = (position / video.duration) * 100 + '%';

      // ..create marker and give it the left value..
      const marker = document.createElement('div');
      marker.classList.add('bubles');
      marker.style.left = left;

      // ..and add the marker to the #seekbar.
      seekBar.appendChild(marker);
    }
  });
});
```

This would place each marker on the timeline with a percentage value. After the loop continue with listening to the `timeupdate` event.

If you want to incorporate *ranges*, like in your example, than it would require some modification. But this will help get you started on where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this previous answer on a similar question, I think you will find your solution there. Answered by vnponce.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127919/12212335