# Start a html5 video of second 30 by link - Chaptermaker

Tags: jquery

There is a chapter maker on YouTube (E.G. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo Description Field). Can you also do this with jquery or other things?

```
<video id="myvideo" width="1000" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4#t=88" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

With `#t=88` I can start in at second 88.
But what if I have 5 links (a href), where I want to start the video from different seconds by link, like this:

```
<a href="video.mp4">00:53 Chapter 1</a>
<a href="video.mp4">01:53 Chapter 2</a>
<a href="video.mp4">02:23 Chapter 3</a>
<a href="video.mp4">03:08 Chapter 4</a>
<a href="video.mp4">04:53 Chapter 5</a>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markers on video timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890099/markers-on-video-timeline)

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE***: This answer is valid for a video hosted on YouTube:

---

An easy way to do this is add in the URL the specific timestamp:

Example:

If for your video, you want to add a timestamp at `1:28`, you could modify the URL as follows:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo&t=1m28s

Note the letters in the URL (*next to the numbers*), in this case, we set the mark at 1 minute and 28 seconds.

For the rest of the marks, those can be done like these examples:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo&t=53s">00:53 Chapter 1</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo&t=1m53s">01:53 Chapter 2</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo&t=2m23s">02:23 Chapter 3</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo&t=3m8s">03:08 Chapter 4</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC_KdEVCLdo&t=4m53s">04:53 Chapter 5</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I don't want to publish my video on Youtube, but on my own website with the video tag. But I have found this what helps me: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/pvPoPq